# Azure CLI function app access-restriction "has host bits set"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I'm trying to add a rule to enable requests from a devops pipeline to an azure function app.

I run the following az cli command (either from the pipeline or from a VS Code terminal window)

```
az functionapp config access-restriction add -g rg-name-here -n func-name-here --rule-name devopsRB --action Allow --ip-address "51.142.236.175/27" --priority 146
```

This gives back the following error:

> 51.142.236.175/27 has host bits set

If I add the same rule via the Azure portal it works ok.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `51.142.236.175/27 has host bits set` also occurred to me. But I ran Azure CLI task with command
`az functionapp config access-restriction add -g GROUP -n NAME --rule-name RULEname --action Allow --ip-address 51.142.0.0/27 --priority 300`
successfully. Consider using 51.142.0.0/27.

Comment: That makes sense since the /27 means 3 octets + 3 bits of the ip address are "owned" by the network - leaving just the last 5 bits for the host